# jQuery: Event can't work on the element which is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is:

When I press the "Show numbers" button, Javascript dynamically create two elements whose class is "number". I expect the computer will console the text of the element which I click. But no matter how hard I try to click the elements, my computer console nothing.

HTML (Pug):

```
 button#btn show numbers
 .numberlist
```

Produced HTML:

```
<button id="btn">show numbers</button>
<div class="numberlist"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $("#btn").click(
   function(){
     $(".numberlist").html("<div class='number'>1</div><div class='number'>2</div>");
   }
 );

 $(".number").click(
   function(){
     console.log("You click number "+$(this).text());
   }
 );
```

[It's](http://codepen.io/yuan0318/pen/eKypzv?editors=1011) the page on Codepen.

Comment: try using $(document).on("click",".number", function() { /*your code* /});

Comment: Can you show us the real html?

Comment: https://codepen.io/yuan0318/pen/eKypzv?editors=1011

Comment: This is my page on Codepen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the html?  Not everyone can access offsite paste sites, and those links can go dead for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use event delegation; since `$(".number")` is targeting an element with `class="number"` and assigning an event, that element needs to be present when the function is defined. Since you're appending (via `.html`) that element, it does not exist when your function is declared. To handle this, use:

```
$("body").on("click", ".number", function(){
  console.log("You click number "+$(this).text());
});
```

This will assign the click handler to any elements in `body` that have a class of `.number`, even ones that are added dynamically.

Comment: Thank you guys!!! I know what the problem is. It's my first time to post a question on StackOverFlow and I'm really nervous about my poor English. I just learn about how to dynamically add the html, so I didn't sense the problem when I coding. Thanks again!!!